# Prevent overscroll in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

Running Ice-Cream Sandwich.

I have the following in my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/caption" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:id="@+id/itemized_list" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Next, I populate this list using an ArrayAdapter and the following layout for list items:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/bulletpoint" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/itemized_list_item_text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The rendering is fine - the listview and its items are rendered to fit the screen. However, when I call `listView.scrollBy`, I am able to scroll way past where the content ends and essentially go into the "outer space" without any constraints. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and my solution was to use `listView.smoothScrollBy(distance, 0)`. It probably has a higher overhead, but it gets the job done.